# How to check if Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime is installed C#

Tags: c#-4.0, report-viewer2012

In my demo application, there is a requirement where I have to check that Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime is installed on client machine, on that basis i have to perform some task, but I'm not able get how to check Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime programatically using C# code.

I have search on the internet but I'm able to find anything which help me.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

All the installed applications shall have some entries in registry. Using that entries we can check the application is installed or not.

Please refer this code project article : [Software's List Installed on Windows Machine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29782/Software-s-List-Installed-on-Windows-Machine)